# Ajax sending to php then echo in div

Tags: html, ajax

I have an ajax function that sends a variable - num - to a php script and then echos the value of num in a div with id "status".

First what happens is the user makes a post, i run all the necessary queries and display the users posts in a div called "posts" (use a while loop so each post is in a div with the same id but the div's are under one and other). I would like the ajax functionality to work in every one of these "posts" divs (each "posts" div contains the two js buttons witch - onclick - manage the ajax function as well as a "status" div)

However every time i click one of the buttons, lets say in the bottom most visible "posts" div displayed (the button clicked calls the ajax/js function), the function carries out in the top most "posts" div where the first "status" div is whereas it should be displaying in the bottom most div where i clicked the button.

Comment: Post your jQuery. My guess is you have more than one div with the ID 'status'.

Comment: Can you post your code or link to an example please

Comment: Sounds like you do not have a unique way of referencing the DIVs so it is just grabbing the first matching element.

Comment: @Treffynnon, yeah is there any way to uniquely identify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, I was assuming you were using jQuery. My bad.

You should be using classes instead of IDs. If you use an ID jquery will only have an effect on the first one in the DOM. IDs should only be used once per page.

Use classes, then reference the divs you want to edit not only by class name, by some sort of reference to the post div you are interacting with.

```
$('.posts .button').click(function() {
  //do ajax stuff...
  $(this).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
}
```

Updated code:

```
// .posts should be the class of the posts div
// .button should be the class of the button on which you are activating your ajax
$('.posts .button').click(function() { 
    $.post('your ajax post URL', function(data) {
       $(this).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
    })
});
```

Comment: if you are using jQuery ajax functions that will be the return from the ajax. Check out the second code snippet on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ Sorry if I just assumed you were using jQuery. I would recommend it obviously. It would make doing what you are trying to do very easy.

Comment: If i understand correctly This example fetches the requested HTML snippet and inserts it on the page. need the ajax function to work in the specified "status" div, not the first "status" div it grabs, can i use it for this too?

Comment: With this jQuery example, $(this) means the actual button that was clicked, the parent is the .posts div. This is referencing the actual div in which the button was clicked, not the first div on the page. The next step is find('.status'), we are still within the .posts div the button was clicked in, so when we modify it we are only modifying that specific .status element. This is doing what @Treffynnon meant by 'uniquely referencing the div'. You should check out some jQuery ajax examples and jQuery selectors. You could do everything you need to do in probably around 8 lines of jQuery.